# Does MySQL WHERE parameter order matter?

Tags: mysql, doctrine, query-performance

Let's pretend I have a database of 1.25 million cats.

10% of the cats are male, and 90% are female.

1% of the cats are named Bob.

30% of the cats like the color blue.

If I make a query that says

`select * from cats where gender="male" and name="Bob" and favorite_color="blue";`

Does the ordering of the where statements make any difference on the performance?

In this case, the 3 parameters are all on the same table, but you could theoretically search by gender
first to weed out 90% of the possible results. Would splitting into multiple queries help?
What would be the best way to optimize this search besides removing the  wildcard *  ? Thank you!

Comment: *Does the ordering of the where statements make any difference on the performance?* No. *Would splitting into multiple queries help?* No. *What would be the best way to optimize this search besides removing the wildcard `*` ?* Depends on columns needed.

Answer (score 0):

> Does the ordering of the where statements make any difference on the performance?

**No**, it does not.

MySQL's query planner (like practically all SQL query planners) looks for the most efficient way to satisfy each query. It considers various approaches and picks an efficient one. Generally it looks at the indexes on the table. You have three where criteria mentioning equality. So, a compound index on the three columns `(name, gender, favorite_color)` will speed up that query dramatically.

There's something counterintuitive about SQL for most programmers. It is *declarative.* That is, you tell it *what you want*, not *how to get it.* It's up to the query planner to figure out how to get it.

That's a really good thing. Why? Database tables have very long lives (decades, sometimes) in production. As they grow, and as the software accessing them changes, the best way to get what you want from them changes. You don't have to worry about those changes, except by adding indexes as needed.

Please consider reading this:  https://use-the-index-luke.com/

Answer (score 0):

```
INDEX(gender), INDEX(name), INDEX(favorite_color)
```

is an inadequate way to optimize that query.

```
INDEX(gender, name, favorite_color)
```

with the columns *in any order* will make for *the given* query to be very efficient.

The order of `WHERE` clauses does not impact performance`

The order of columns in an `INDEX` *does* matter, sometimes a lot.  However it does not matter *for the given query*, since each test is `=`.